# How to click one id from a list of ids?

Tags: javascript

I have a list of ids, when one of them is clicked I want to give it the attribute `.className="open`.
So far what I've done is to put all ids in a list and try to loop through them.

```
      const memberB = document.querySelectorAll('#memberA, #memberAA, #memberAAA ');
  for (var i = 0; i < memberB.length; i++) {
    memberB[i].onclick = function(){
        alert(memberB[i])
        if(memberB[i].className=="open"){
            memberB[i].className="";
        }
        else{
            memberB[i].className="open";
        }
  }
```

What did I do wrong, I try to alert to see if I get the element that i clicked, all i get is 'undefined'.

Comment: Note that your `var i` is a shared reference, so whenever any member is clicked, it will check the `i` at that moment (i.e. some time after the loop has finished), which would be `memberB.length` this time, so you'll only get undefined for `memberB[i]`.
One way to separate the reference for each iteration is by using `let i` instead of `var i`.

Comment: another solution is to use `this` in the event handler as it will be the element the handler is handling

Comment: Can you show your HTML as well?

Comment: @yousoumar - you don't need the HTML to see what's wrong!

Comment: You are right @Bravo, no need for it. Should have been more focused, or read qrsngky's answer, sorry.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use `forEach` to loop the `NodeList` which use `querySelectorAll` method, and use `addEventListener` to watch click event happen on all the elements you selected. Finally, use `Element.classList.toggle` method to toggle the class open or close

there is an example of toggle its background color after click

```js
const members = document.querySelectorAll('.member');
members.forEach(member => {
  member.addEventListener('click', e => {
    e.target.classList.toggle('hight-light');
  });
});
```

```css
.member {
  background-color: gray;
}

.hight-light {
  background-color: green;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="member">1</div>
  <div class="member hight-light">2</div>
  <div class="member">3</div>
  <div class="member">4</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

I have a code snippet I like to keep around to do these kind of things in a single event listener

```js
window.addEvent = (event_type, target, callback) => {
  document.addEventListener(event_type, function (event) {
    // If the event doesn't have a target
    // Or the target doesn't look like a DOM element (no matches method
    // Bail from the listener
    if (event.target && typeof (event.target.matches) === 'function') {
      if (!event.target.matches(target)) {
        // If the element triggering the event is contained in the selector
        // Copy the event and trigger it on the right target (keep original in case)
        if (event.target.closest(target)) {
          const new_event = new CustomEvent(event.type, event);
          new_event.data = { originalTarget: event.target };
          event.target.closest(target).dispatchEvent(new_event);
        }
      } else {
        callback(event);
      }
    }
  });
};
```

then in your case I'd do this

```js
window.addEvent('click', '#memberA,#memberAA,#memberAAA', (event) => {
 event.target.classList.toggle('open');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

The script runs befor the DOM elements load.

You can put the script as a function inside an `$(document).ready` such that it runs after all the elements have been loaded.

```js
$(document).ready(
        function () {
            const memberB = document.querySelectorAll('#memberA, #memberAA, #memberAAA ');
            for (let i = 0; i < memberB.length; i++) {
                memberB[i].onclick = function () {
                    //alert(memberB[i])
                    if (memberB[i].className === "open") {
                        memberB[i].className = "";
                    } else {
                        memberB[i].className = "open";
                    }
                    alert(memberB[i].className)
                }
            }
        })
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="memberA">A</button>
<button id="memberAA">AA</button>
<button id="memberAAA">AAA</button>
```

Let me know if this works!